# What would happen if trying to lock an entity a second time within the same transaction?

Tags: java, spring-boot, locking

What would happen if trying to lock an entity a second time within the same transaction?

I am developing small software with Spring boot framework.
There is one big transactional process. At the beginning of this process, I retrieve an entity with  Pessimistic Locking.
Then at the end of the process, If I try to retrieve an entity with locking again, does spring boot run select query on database again?

Comment: Why not try it out?